# listview: getting subitem text

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview

i have a listview with the following columns id, surname, firstname. i want to get the surname when a row is selected how do i do it using visual c# 2008?

Comment: Challenge? Perhaps you should change your title to something more descriptive.

Comment: This smells like homework. I'll give you a hint: It involves ListViewItem.SubItems

Answer (score 4):

subscribing SelectedIndexChanged for ListView1:

```
ListView1.SelectedItems[0].Subitems[1].Text
```

you have some tons of microsoft documentation about it..

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.listviewsubitem.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You have to obtain the selected Item: `SelectedItem`, then look in the SubItems collection. In general we can say that is better to have some object bound to the item ( for example in the tag ) and obtain back th einformation from it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `SelectedIndexChanged` Event or `ItemActivate` (if you want to double click the item before it fires whatever work you want).

```
listView1.SelectedItems[0].Subitems[1].Text
```

Remember that `SubItems` start at zero index and in your surname column is in index of 1. Column id takes the zero index.